# Import pyglet on python

Tags: python, import, module, pydev, pyglet

I have downloaded the pyglet.dmg file from [pyglet website](http://www.pyglet.org/) and simply installed it.

The folder on which it is saved is: `/Developer/pyglet`

And on the pydev editor i simply state the location i want to use by:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('Developer/pyglet')
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

But for some reason i cant get this import:

```
python sound.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sound.py", line 3, in <module>
import pyglet
ImportError: No module named pyglet
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it.

I just downloaded the [source files](http://www.pyglet.org/download.html) and compiled it by myself by invoking:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

And then simply used the sys import as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add path slash.

```
sys.path.append('/Developer/pyglet')
                 ^
```